# Use lodash to group array into tree “children” structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, lodash

I am trying to create a tree using the array of json objects below. I want to set a category as a child of another category if its sub_category_1 and I want the sub_category_2 also to be a children of that sub_category_1

```
[
  { 
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: null,
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'TS',
    sub_category_1: null,
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: 'Accuracy',
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: 'Accuracy',
    sub_category_2: 'Members Accuracy'
  }
]
```

I've attempted to chain lodash methods like groupBy and transform, but am having a hard time getting to the resulting format I require.

Here's a skeleton of what direction I was heading:

```
_(arr).groupBy('category').transform(function(result, obj, type) {
 return result.push({
    name: type,
    children: obj
 });
}).value();
```

Expected output :

```
[{
    category: 'CS',
        children: [
            {
                category: 'Accuracy',
                children: [
                    {
                        category: 'Members Accuracy'
                    }
                    ...
                ]
            }
            ...
        ]
    }, {
    category: 'TS'
 }]
```

Comment: can you give a example of what you want

Comment: @JagadishLenka _"Here's a skeleton of what direction I was heading: ..."_

Comment: It has to be lodash? There should be suitable duplicates with vanilla JS

Comment: are you the creator of that weird json ??

Comment: It was created by different person. thats why its too hard for me to group and make a tree json data using lodash

Comment: @JagadishLenka seems like a normal flattened hierarchy list of items. For building up menus or other similar things with multiple levels. If the data is stored in a RDBMS it's usually just a bunch of entries in a single table, so it's naturally flat. It can be easily post-processed into nested.

Comment: Why people create problem, And later trying to fix that problem... @StoledInk, You should manage your data structure properly...

Comment: Basically this was the structure https://imgur.com/a/dl4HRNh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that the category descriptions will come in the correct order (main, then sub-category, then sub-sub-category) you can use vanilla JavaScript to build up the tree:

```js
// data constructor for a category
const Category = (category, children = []) =>
  ({ category, children });

// 1. Ensure only the `sub_category_n` values are taken and
// 2. they are in ascending order and
// 3. any null values are removed
const subCategories = obj => 
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => /sub_category_\d+/.test(key))
    .filter(([, value]) => value != null)
    .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB, {numeric: true}))
    .map(([, subCategoryName]) => subCategoryName);

// take a category descriptor and turn it into full path of category names:
// { category: "X", sub_category_1: "Y", sub_category_1: "Z" }
// turns into ["X", "Y", "Z"]
const toPath = ({category, ...sub}) =>
  [category, ...subCategories(sub)];

// create a key from the path elements separated by Unit Separator characters
// or return a unique symbol for no parent
const toKey = (path) =>
  path.join("\u241F") || Symbol("no parent");
  
const toHierarchy = arr => {
  const result = [];
  //keep track of categories that have been created
  const seen = new Map();
    
  for (const item of arr) {
    const path = toPath(item);
    //last item in the path is what we want to create
    const childName = path[path.length-1];
    
    //parent key is the path without the last item
    const parentKey = toKey(path.slice(0, -1));
    //the child key is the full path
    const childKey = toKey(path)
    
    //skip if it's seen
    if (seen.has(childKey))
      continue;
      
    const child = Category(childName);
    seen.set(childKey, child);

    //if there is no parent, add as a main category. Otherwise as a child
    const parentList = seen.get(parentKey)?.children ?? result;
    parentList.push(child);
  }
  
  return result;
}


const input = [
  { 
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: null,
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'TS',
    sub_category_1: null,
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: 'Accuracy',
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: 'Accuracy',
    sub_category_2: 'Members Accuracy'
  }
];

console.log(toHierarchy(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If the list of categories might be unordered, you can analyse the whole path and create any missing categories, not just one per object:

```js
const Category = (category, children = []) =>
  ({ category, children });

const subCategories = obj => 
  Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => /sub_category_\d+/.test(key))
    .filter(([, value]) => value != null)
    .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA.localeCompare(keyB, {numeric: true}))
    .map(([, subCategoryName]) => subCategoryName);
    
const toPath = ({category, ...sub}) =>
  [category, ...subCategories(sub)];
  
const toKey = (path, key = []) =>
  path.concat(key).join("\u241F") || Symbol("no parent");

const toHierarchy = arr => {
  const result = [];
  const seen = new Map()
    
  for (const item of arr) {
    const path = toPath(item);
    for (const [index, childName] of path.entries()) {
      const parentKey = toKey(path.slice(0, index));
      const childKey = toKey(path.slice(0, index+1));
      if (!seen.has(childKey)) {
        const child = Category(childName);
        seen.set(childKey, child);
        
        const parentList = seen.get(parentKey)?.children ?? result;
        parentList.push(child);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}


const input = [
  {
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: 'Accuracy',
    sub_category_2: null
  }, { 
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: null,
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'TS',
    sub_category_1: null,
    sub_category_2: null
  }, {
    category: 'CS',
    sub_category_1: 'Accuracy',
    sub_category_2: 'Members Accuracy'
  }
];

console.log(toHierarchy(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This fails if two top-level categories have a sub-category of the same value.

Comment: As in `{category: "A", sub_category_1: "X" }` and `{ category: "B", sub_category_1: "X" }`?

Comment: Yes, I think it's because of the way you are tracking `seen`, it diverts all `sub-categories` of the same name to a single reference (and all children thereof)

Comment: Hmm, would be. I assumed that the names of the categories are unique. But you're right, they might not be.

Comment: Changed how the lookup is done. Instead of just basing the key on the name, it's the whole path separated by a Unit Separator character.

Comment: @VLAZ I would like to ask if it is possible to include id of each categories? advance thanks for the solution

Comment: @StoledInk add it how? What should the values be? You can modify the `Category` data constructor to add an automatic `id` field, if needed.

Comment: @VLAZ ID from post process results will be included in each category please refer to the link below for your reference https://jsfiddle.net/9v7nh1qs/1/

Comment: @StoledInk [add the ID to the data constructor, then pass the ID when you call the data constructor](https://jsfiddle.net/nk2duow4/)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the best solution would be to refactor the underlying data source to return a more usable result.

But barring that you can use a straightforward nested `reduce()` call.

I'm sorting the child keys of each top-level category to avoid relying on object property ordering, and assuming that each element will begin with a top-level `category`.

```js
const
  input = [{ category: 'CS', sub_category_1: null, sub_category_2: null }, { category: 'TS', sub_category_1: null, sub_category_2: null }, { category: 'CS', sub_category_1: 'Accuracy', sub_category_2: null }, { category: 'CS', sub_category_1: 'Accuracy', sub_category_2: 'Members Accuracy' }],

  tree = Object.values(
    input.reduce((acc, { category, ...children }) => {
      acc[category] ??= { category, children: [] };

      // sort child keys so as to not rely on object property ordering
      const subcategories = Object.entries(children).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b));

      // reduce child keys into category
      subcategories.reduce((_acc, [, subcategory]) => {
        if (subcategory === null) return _acc;

        let sub = _acc.children.find(({ category }) => category === subcategory);
        if (!sub) {
          sub = { category: subcategory, children: [] };
          _acc.children.push(sub);
        }
        return sub
      }, acc[category]);

      return acc;
    }, {})
  );


console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```